# Configure apache to run node.js app

Tags: php, node.js, apache, .htaccess, redirect

My `.htaccess config`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:47777/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:47777/$1 [P,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index\.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://127.0.0.1:47777/ [R=301,L]
```

**I'm successfully able to host my node app on the server using above redirect but the issue is that it expects `index.php` to be the route
Like 
When I access URL: `example.com` it rewrites to `127.0.0.1:47777/index.php`
But the route index.php is not defined.**

I tried the above snippet:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index\.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://127.0.0.1:47777/ [R=301,L]
```

But it still adds index.php to the end of the route.

*Note: I'm on a shared hosting so I can't access apache root configs *

Comment: You have a Rewrite rule without conditions : RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:47777/ [P,L]

Comment: I have tried removing it and a number of other configurations as well but no success. Moreover, it redirects when URL string is empty. @Erez.S